# Show message after deleting the last item

Tags: android

I have list of items, I can delete them, as soon as delete the last one, 
I want to get a message “just Log.e(“deleted”,”the last one”);”

Would you please help me in this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting a file, call `new File("/path/to/folder").listFiles().length` - if length is 0, this means the last file was just deleted.

Comment: it is only the case if the directory has one file what happens when there are multiple files. The thing to do would be to check if the file exists after deletion

Comment: Why ? Suppose he has n files, he starts deleting them one by one, when he deletes the last file and checks for the number of files it'll be zero. That's when he gets to know that the last file has been deleted. The rest of the times listFiles().length will have a positive non zero value.

Comment: it seems logical but not the best way

Comment: If he checks if the file exists after deletion, it'll just tell him that the last file was deleted or not, but he wont get to know if that file was the last file or not.